# Issue after deleting and adding platform on ionic

Tags: ios, ionic3, cordova-plugins, provisioning-profile

I have an app developed in ionic 3, and I was resolving a problem with apple store connect.The solution I found was remove ios platform by the project, add it again and then reinstall the camera plugin. After I made it, I can't build the app on terminal to deploy it on a device or on the simulator.

My Ionic and Cordova Info

Ionic:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
```

Cordova:

```
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 13 other plugins)
```

The commands I've used: ionic cordova platform rm ios, ionic cordova platform add ios, ionic plugin remove camera-plugin, ionic plugin add camera-plugin.

I've already tried uncheck and check the "Automatically manage signing" on Xcode, and is still not working with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I re-added the ios platform, ionic has been created another xcode file project in platforms/ios/. So I opened this new project and unchecked and checked again the option "Automatically manage signing", at the General option menu.